# AWS Elastic Beanstalk error when accessing RDS using encryption: "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted"

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

In less than a year the SSL/TLS certs used for AWS RDS (SQL Server) is going to expire so they recommend everyone update their older RDS instances to use the newer certs. I changed my RDS SQL instance to use the new cert and updated my ASP.Net 4.8 app to use "Encryption=True;TrustServerCertificate=True" in the connection string. I then verified that the connection is encrypted by checking SYS.DM_EXEC_CONNECTIONS in the database when the site is being used.

However, if I set TrustServerCertificate=False in the connection string, which is what it should be, the site won't start and I get an error logged that "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when trying to create the database connection.

On my dev system I was able to add Amazon's root certs so it can verify the cert chain and I can now stop trusting the server cert when doing local testing. I expected that Elastic Beanstalk instances would already have the Amazon root certs configured but it appears that is not the case.

Is there something that I need to do with the EB configuration so it will recognize the newer root certs so it can verify the cert chain for the RDS connection?

This EB instance does use a load balancer but I would think that only impacts incoming SSL/TLS connections, not outbound connections.

Update: I should point out that this RDS instance is not directly a part of my EB instance. I set RDS up separately from my EB instance.